# Program slows down when vector becomes bigger

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, vector

In a larger program I have a for loop where in each iteration a `std::vector`
 of `cv::Mat` matrices is generated, (each element comes from a cv::filter2D call with different kernel). Each such vector is ~90MB in size and is supposed to be one case in a training set.

When pushing back these vectors in another `vector` (or `list`, to save all cases in the training set), the loop gets slower and slower (especially filter2d takes longer and longer, even if the images are always the same size). Of course the memory consumption goes up, but the effect already starts very early when using about 2GB out of 100GB of free RAM.

Any ideas how to speed up things? (windows 8 x64, visual studio 2012 x64)

Comment: Please specify what OS and compiler do you use. For example - Windows x64, VC++ 2015 x64

Comment: Copying vector data implies new memory. The OS provides this new memory, which is slow. Try reserving plenty of memory instead of asking for a lot of small chunks. If used memory is so big (2 GB) the OS likely uses hard-disk pagefile memory, which is really slow compared to RAM.

Comment: It only slows down when saving the 90MB vectors into another vector (and it's not the saving that's slow). There is still about 100GB of free memory, that's why I'm wondering why it gets slower.

Comment: You really have 100GB of ram on your system? Wow! If not, you simply have the first amount of datal in ram and later memory requests go to swap space on HDD which is very slow. BTW: Why at all you copy vectors into other vectors?

Comment: Yes, 128GB with 100GB being free, so no HDD involved. It's for generating and saving a training set.

Comment: @user1225905: Klaus put a valid question: Why do you need to copy vectors. Could you provide more details on this?

Comment: Each vector generated in the loop will be one case in a training set, so I have to store them in this training set (i.e. the second vector that gets bigger and bigger).

Comment: Try reusing vectors from previous iterations, use `std::resize`, `std::reserve` and `cv::Mat::create()` instead of reallocation. If you cannot overwrite, try storing the older data to a file. Try preallocating you data.

Comment: Yes, we pre-allocated most of the memory, but the effect that the speed decreases is still there. What makes me wonder is that even filter2d gets slower with time.